Location doesn't work correctly in Telegram Mini App
I am developing a mini application that uses the user's location. I am utilizing the recent API from Telegram Mini Apps: https://core.telegram.org/bots/webapps#locationmanager.
When retrieving the geolocation, it behaves quite strangely. Sometimes, when I’m driving in a car, it works perfectly, including the speed at which the device is moving. But more often, it simply doesn’t work, and the speed value is -1.
What could be causing this behavior? Is it a bug on the messenger’s side, given that this issue appeared quite recently? Or is it a problem with my device?
